# Tensor("dense_2/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 10), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm running this program with tensorflow==1.14.0 and Keras==2.3.0, my code works fine with tensorflow==2.2.0 and Keras==2.4.3. However due to some reason, I need to decrease my overall package size to be < 500MB ([Heroku: deploying Deep Learning model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840025/heroku-deploying-deep-learning-model)), therefore I want to use an earlier version of tensorflow instead. However, with tensorflow==1.14.0 and Keras==2.3.0 my program gives **ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_2/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 10), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.** whenever I try to make a prediction (inside the predict_class function).

Does anyone know why is that? I've scan though many other problems but they don't seem to be resolving this issue or they're just leading me to another error.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('wordnet')
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
import numpy as np
import pickle
import json
import random
from django.http import JsonResponse

from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('chatbot/model.h5')
intents = json.loads(open('chatbot/intents.json').read())
words = pickle.load(open('chatbot/words.pkl', 'rb'))
classes = pickle.load(open('chatbot/classes.pkl', 'rb'))


def clean_up_user_input(sentence):
  sentence_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
  sentence_words = [
      lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in sentence_words
  ]
  return sentence_words


def get_bag_of_words(sentence, words):
  sentence_words = clean_up_user_input(sentence)
  bag = [0] * len(words)
  for s in sentence_words:
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
      if word == s:
        bag[i] = 1

  return np.array(bag)


def predict_class(sentence):
  # filter below  threshold predictions
  p = get_bag_of_words(sentence, words)
  res = model.predict(np.array([p]))[0]
  ERROR_THRESHOLD = 0.25
  results = [[i, r] for i, r in enumerate(res) if r > ERROR_THRESHOLD]
  # sorting strength probability
  results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
  return_list = []
  for r in results:
    return_list.append({"intent": classes[r[0]], "probability": str(r[1])})
  if return_list == []:
    return_list.append({"intent": 'noanswer', "probability": str(1)})
  return return_list
```

This is how I train the model

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
import random
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
import json
import pickle

words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_letters = ['!', '?', ',', '.']
intents_file = open('intents.json').read()
intents = json.loads(intents_file)

for intent in intents['intents']:
  for pattern in intent['patterns']:
    word = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
    words.extend(word)
    #add documents in the corpus
    documents.append((word, intent['tag']))
    # add to our classes list
    if intent['tag'] not in classes:
      classes.append(intent['tag'])

print(documents)
# lemmaztize and lower each word and remove duplicates
words = [
    lemmatizer.lemmatize(w.lower()) for w in words if w not in ignore_letters
]
words = sorted(list(set(words)))
# sort classes
classes = sorted(list(set(classes)))
# documents = combination between patterns and intents
print(len(documents), "documents")
# classes = intents
print(len(classes), "classes", classes)
# words = all words, vocabulary
print(len(words), "unique lemmatized words", words)

pickle.dump(words, open('words.pkl', 'wb'))
pickle.dump(classes, open('classes.pkl', 'wb'))

# create the training data
training = []
# create an empty array for our output
output_empty = [0] * len(classes)
# training set, bag of words for each sentence
for doc in documents:
  # initialize our bag of words
  bag = []
  # list of tokenized words for the pattern
  pattern_words = doc[0]
  # lemmatize each word - create base word, in attempt to represent related words
  pattern_words = [
      lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in pattern_words
  ]
  # create our bag of words array with 1, if word match found in current pattern
  for word in words:
    bag.append(1) if word in pattern_words else bag.append(0)

  # output is a '0' for each tag and '1' for current tag (for each pattern)
  output_row = list(output_empty)
  output_row[classes.index(doc[1])] = 1

  training.append([bag, output_row])

# shuffle our features and turn into np.array
random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training)

# create train and test lists. X - patterns, Y - intents
train_x = list(training[:, 0])
train_y = list(training[:, 1])
print("Training data created")

# Create model - 3 layers. First layer 128 neurons, second layer 64 neurons and 3rd output layer contains number of neurons
# equal to number of intents to predict output intent with softmax
# Sequential() allows you to create models layer-by-layer
model = Sequential()
# Dense layer is a regular layer of neurons in a neural network
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]), ), activation='relu'))
# Dropout is used for prevent overfitting.
# Dropout works by randomly setting the outgoing edges of hidden units (neurons that make up hidden layers) to 0 at each update of the training phase
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax'))

# Compile model. Stochastic gradient descent with Nesterov accelerated gradient gives good results for this model
# nesterov is an optimal method (in terms of oracle complexity) for smooth convex optimization
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
# loss is the loss function
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# fitting and saving the model
# By setting verbose 0, 1 or 2 you just say how do you want to 'see' the training progress for each epoch.
# The batch size defines the number of samples that will be propagated through the network
hist = model.fit(np.array(train_x),
                 np.array(train_y),
                 epochs=200,
                 batch_size=5,
                 verbose=1)
model.save('model.h5', hist)
```

Comment: Is your initial model created with Tensorflow 2.2 oder Tensorflow 1.14? Downgrading may be problematic, since the difference between the versions is major.

Comment: I have updated the question to include my train.py. I've retrained the model and run the prediction but the same error remains. Both training and predicting are under the same environment

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved by adding a few lines of code, I have marked the end of line with '#'

for additional details, pls check out https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28287

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model #
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import set_session # 
import tensorflow as tf #
graph = tf.get_default_graph() #
sess = tf.Session() #
set_session(sess) #

model = load_model('chatbot/model.h5')
intents = json.loads(open('chatbot/intents.json').read())
words = pickle.load(open('chatbot/words.pkl', 'rb'))
classes = pickle.load(open('chatbot/classes.pkl', 'rb'))


def clean_up_user_input(sentence):
  sentence_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
  sentence_words = [
      lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in sentence_words
  ]
  return sentence_words


def get_bag_of_words(sentence, words):
  sentence_words = clean_up_user_input(sentence)
  bag = [0] * len(words)
  for s in sentence_words:
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
      if word == s:
        bag[i] = 1

  return np.array(bag)


def predict_class(sentence):
  # filter below  threshold predictions
  p = get_bag_of_words(sentence, words)
  
  with graph.as_default(): #
    set_session(sess) #
    res = model.predict(np.array([p]))[0]

  ERROR_THRESHOLD = 0.25
  results = [[i, r] for i, r in enumerate(res) if r > ERROR_THRESHOLD]
  # sorting strength probability
  results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
  return_list = []
  for r in results:
    return_list.append({"intent": classes[r[0]], "probability": str(r[1])})
  if return_list == []:
    return_list.append({"intent": 'noanswer', "probability": str(1)})
  return return_list
```